# How to retrieve the error description and details for Just-in-Time Provisioning errors for SAML

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, provisioning

Usually the errors are returned in the URL parameters of the error page. Since I've created a custom page to be redirected when a SAML error (portal user login) occurs, I would like to display the error description and detail in that page.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looking for the referrer URL in the HTTP headers on your custom page?

Comment: hey @metadaddy. Yup. I'm trying to use String Referrer = apexpages.currentPage().getheaders().get('Referer');

Comment: With what result?

Comment: I have used referer URL and split method to obtain the parameter values. The custom page is saved in the CUSTOM ERROR URL field in the Single Sign-On Settings. The User profile has the custom page access. But when there is a login error, the SSO login page is redirecting to custom page and the vice versa. This is recursive and no page is opening. I’m trying to figure out where the issue is. Once the custom page is loaded then I can test it. @metadaddy you have any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

For the infinite redirect issue, it is because you have not made the error page to be publicly available. You can make it publicly available through site "Public access" button